# Search block in fixed bar issue

Tags: theming, entities, search

I've added the search block to my fixed navigation bar at the top of the page (the nav bar is fixed when you scroll the page). The problem is that searching for the term leads to no where. When I enter a word in the search field and submit, the page simply refreshes and no search page results is shown.

The search block is placed in a region I created that goes in the fixed nav bar, which is a php include in a separate php file.

The address bar brings up the following query.

> /?search_block_form=regardless&form_build_id=form-z5VjHhWMMLVlbCpugfuhle7ETfQxjhL9vCmIGq9ZdW0&form_token=c4WPVTbY1GKQOXvFraDuX9e7Nn-41wQWYiS3zJ-jkJs&form_id=search_block_form

Comment: What's the `action` attribute on the form set to?

Comment: @clive inspecting the search block code in the browser from the shows '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></span></div><button class="element-invisible btn btn-primary form-submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Search" type="submit">Search</button>
<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-4zwShna7vOjI8xLcqHEHaXpr0XF3twS_nMMe5YA7-ag">
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="c4WPVTbY1GKQOXvFraDuX9e7Nn-41wQWYiS3zJ-jkJs">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="search_block_form">'

Comment: @clive I forgot to mention I am using bootstrap 3 and the following is the region code in the nav file where the search form goes'<div class="form-group">
          <div class="search-control"><?php print render($page['site_search']) ?></div>
        </div>'